# How do you Select a Time Step for Molecular Dynamics Simulations?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, mathematical-modeling, lammps, vibrations, interatomic-potentials

It seems there is a general agreement among the practitioners of Molecular Dynamics that 1fs is a fairly reasonable time step, with shorter time steps being required for materials with higher vibrational frequencies. But I haven't seen much information on how one might derive the highest vibrational frequency of a material.

The following question from this site is related: [How should one choose the time step in a molecular dynamics integration?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/498/how-should-one-choose-the-time-step-in-a-molecular-dynamics-integration/514?newreg=8271db8e38504b1593c741a5a4dfcdd3)

The question has two great answers referencing Nyquist's Theorem and explaining the reasoning behind choosing a timestep frequency below the highest vibrational frequency, but when it comes to establishing if the timestep you've chosen is appropriate it suggests empirically checking various timesteps for energy drift.

Having read around further it seems there are a few other methods for establishing the correct time step, and they are below along with the empirical method:

1. Empirically check the time-step is correct by performing NVE simulations and checking for energy drift.
2. Use the first crossing point of the "Velocity Auto-Correlation Function" to establish an appropriate time step. Seen here on the LAMMPS source forge mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/p/lammps/mailman/message/26183023/
3. Analyse your Interatomic Pair Potentials to establish what the highest frequency is likely to be and use that as a base for you timestep.

Which method would you recommend as the most mathematically/ physically rigorous, and does anyone know or have a link to the specifics of the latter two methods?

Comment: Do you want an answer about which of these is the most rigorous or which methods are most useful? The latter is more subjective. As you pointed out on https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/498/how-should-one-choose-the-time-step-in-a-molecular-dynamics-integration, the Nyquist Theorem is rigorous for a model problem but it's not that useful of a guideline in practice.

IMO, it would be nice if the linked question had more answers of different methods (e.g. those you mention here). Then it could be left up the reader to determine what is the most suitable for them.

Comment: @BrandonBocklund In my mind mathematical rigour and usefulness are reasonably closely intertwined, so either would be completely fine! I suppose realistically the other two methods would be more useful as a "Good First Approximation" which could be confirmed by empirical testing. But an explanation of timestep choice beyond "it gives me what I want" is what I really would like!

Comment: @Connor I agree with Brandon that it would be nice if this prior question could collect answers about the pros/cons of more of these methods that you have mentioned. MD is not my area of expertise, but I expect that there is somewhat of hierarchy of choices from least to most rigorous/unapproximated, but that for a give level/rung, its more a choice of what approximations you choose to make and that this would be fairly system dependent.

Comment: whoops! I posted my answer in the related question, but I hope [my answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6676) over there is useful!

Comment: @dwhswenson Do you mean that your answer to *this* question was accidentally written below the *related* question? We can fix that, if that's the case.

Comment: @NikeDattani : Sort of but not quite. I answered the other question (while reading and considering its text and other answers), but only because I saw this one on the RSS feed for the MD tag. So the answer I wrote belongs over there, as it doesn't directly address the specifics that differentiate this question from that one. (But the articles I linked might still be of some use here!) (More clearly: don't bother moving the answer.)

Comment: @dwhswenson thanks for the clarification! Are you getting emails whenever an MD question is asked? Or by "RSS feed" do you just mean, the questions listed when you click on the MD tag? We also have a couple chat rooms dedicated to MD software, such as [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps) and [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120383/gromacs) :)

Comment: @NikeDattani -- thanks for the info on the chat rooms! I'm using the RSS feed for the tag (hover over tag name, click orange RSS icon in upper right: for MD you'd get the link https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/molecular-dynamics). I use feedly to follow that (usually via Reeder app on phone). It only gives the on-site questions (nothing from chat). I follow a few tags (MD, openpathsampling, software-rec) that interest me. Helps me to be an occasional (but repeating!) contributor.

Comment: Connor, how is this coming along for you? Since it's been a few months, do you have any update about what you've learned about this question since asking it?

Comment: @NikeDattani I would love to update this with an answer but I have only just finished writing my thesis and haven't had the time to put any of these techniques into practice yet! I would actually be interested in joining/ starting a chat about these aspects of molecular dynamics in the future if anyone is interested? My personal thought is that NVE energy drift is easiest (plug and play), and interatomic potential analysis is the most rigorous.

Comment: @Connor if you're interested in joining a chat room about MD, since you've used the LAMMPS tag on this question, perhaps you could start by saying "hello" in here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps

Comment: @Connor how are things now that it's been more than a year since your last comment? Did you ever say "hello" in that LAMMPS chat room? We have a GROMACS one too: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120383/gromacs